# Why is the final column of this table running off the page?

Tags: tables, columns

```
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{tabular}{ l   l   l }
& + -naqa (diffuse) & + -nuqa (placer) \\
\hline
alli- `dig' & `knock over or destroy, to throw something to the floor' &    `destroy or make some construction collapse' \\
jari- `wash' &  `wash here and there' (as when clothing is so dirty, that one does not know where to begin, so starts just washing randomly) & `wash everything which is dirty' \\
    k'uta- `crush' &    `hit something here and there thereby reducing it into various parts' & `hit (chancar) something and destroy it completely' \\ 
kut(a)-t'(a)-  & `return, go back'  `go and come back' (as when someone leaves and returns because he forgot something)  &  `return to one's original place (after some time)' \\
puri- `arrive' & `arrive at various places/houses' (as if homeless)' & `arrive with all one's things when one was previously living elsewhere' \\
sara- `go'  & `walk around as if lost'  &   `stay in a certain place' \\
taki- `kick' &  `step in various places' &  `step cautiously' \\
wali-ch(a)- `arrange, improve'  & `arrange or order something here and there'   `organize or arrange things which were in a bad condition' \\
    wayu- `take something by the handle'    & `bring something from one place to another and back; to move something from hand to hand' & `put something (like a bag) on something' \\
    wawa-cha- `give birth' &    `give birth in various places' (as certain animals may do) &    `give birth' \\
    will(u)- `spill' &  `throw objects into the air haphazardly, as when one is urgently searching for something' & `throw objects from above to below' \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX doesn't break text in cells belonging to columns declared with `l`.

Comment: try using the `p{<width>}` column type

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX doesn't break text in cells belonging to `l` (or `c` or `r`) columns. For automatic breaking you have to declare the column as

```
p{<dimen>}
```

Experiment with `\p{5cm}` or so, then change the width to suit.